# validates acceptance doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model with such validation rule:

```
validates :terms, acceptance: true
```

But this validation works only if I set `terms` attribute to `false` explicitly. If I don't touch this attribute (so it would be `nil`), validation succeeds.

```
user = User.new

user.valid?
=> true

user.terms
=> nil

user.terms = false
user.valid?
=> false

user.terms = true
user.valid?
=> true
```

How I can make this validation fail by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option `allow_nil: false` for the validation which will force to fail in case of `nil` value.

```
validates :terms, acceptance: true, allow_nil: false

user = User.new

user.valid?
=> false

user.terms
=> nil
```